# Eloquent ORM, deleted_at has no index when using soft deleting

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I use `$table->softDeletes()` in a migration, a deleted_at timestamp nullable column is added to the table.

From now on I can come to the conclusion that any query against this table via eloquent will carry a `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` clause, assuring only live records are returned.

But I noticed there is no index created for deleted_at. Shouldn't be paramount for this column to have an index?

I hope I'm missing something.

Comment: You can add it if you feel it's needed.

Comment: `$table->softDeletes()->index();`

Comment: Mr. TLGreg, the command you suggested is tempting, but it triggers `Call to a member function index() on a non-object`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, we're on a fork here where we modified the schema builder (softDeletes() doesn't return back the fluent object in the vanilla method). `$table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable()->index()` should work without a fork, even if it's not that nice. :)

Comment: Ok sir, I'll do that.

Comment: @user2094178 according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26530488/978690), you should not index your deleted_at columns

Comment: @rap-2-h Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525068/does-laravels-soft-delete-need-index-on-mysql/26530488#26530488), you should not index your deleted_at column. There will be no beneficial impact on performance.