# Why does where soft_delete make the query slower by factor 5?

Tags: laravel, mysql-5.7, soft-delete

I have a `users` table using [Laravels Soft Delete](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) which is essentially a null-able `deleted_at` column. If `deleted_at` is null, then the user was not deleted.

I want to count the number for non-deleted users of a 130k users table who have been created after a specific date.

Using

```
`select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `created_at` >= '2019-09-18 10:33:09' and `users`.`deleted_at` is null`;
```

takes 269ms.

Using

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where date(`created_at`) >= '2019-09-18 10:33:09';
```

takes 57ms.

The table contains 137381 users from which 48 users are soft deleted.

I already found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530488/2311074 that `deleted_at` should not be indexed, and actually indexing `deleted_at` is not changing anything.
Also creating a touple index (`created_at`, `deleted_at`) does not change anything.

I was able to imrpove the execution time of the query with

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN  (deleted_at is null) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as aggregate from `users` where date(`created_at`) >= '2019-09-18 10:33:09';
```

which only executes in 78ms but I don't understand what makes the query 5 times slower with the additional where condition?

Using Mysql Explain didnt help me to find out the issue. Here is the result for the 78ms query

[image]

And thats the result for the 269ms query

[image]

Comment: are those values the average from multiple tests ? or you just rerun the query like 10 times ?

Comment: @N69S I executed the query in mysql workbench like 10 times

Comment: That's not enough to benchmark it correctly, was it on production or on local (make sure no other queries are run at the same time). Because i just run a local test with 300k entries and both request are at max 16ms at minimum 15ms with 0 index

Comment: @N69S it was on local. There were no other queries in parallel. I am using a docker container. I am on Ubuntu 20 iwth 16GB Memory andA MD® Ryzen 7 4700u . Did you use mysql 5.7? 15mx without index on 300k indexes sounds crazy fast

Comment: used MySql 5.7.24-winx64 with heidiSQL.